# its not displaying scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf

in this code i want to put scrollbar so for that i did that but its not displaying scroll.?

```
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<Grid Width="387" Height="186" Background="LightBlue"  >

        <TextBox Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="6,6,0,0"  Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" />
        <TextBox Height="110" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="6,122,0,0"   Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Pasting it into a sandbox project, the code seems to work fine. Have you tried it in a sandbox project of your own, to see if it works there? A WPF window with just that code in a grid.

Comment: can any one tell me how to use scrollviewer or scroll bar in wpf with good example?i want scroll in my grid to show long content

Comment: thanks  private_meta,its show scroll in wpf form not grid

Comment: Usually you just use the ScrollViewer like you did, maybe set the Visibility to Auto, so your example in this case is ok anyway. Not sure why it doesn't work for you. What I meant with Grid was I pasted it like this:
`<Window>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>`

Comment: @SANDEEP, when you want to find out something about a .NET class or technology, don't waste your time asking and waiting for an answer here... go straight to the source... MSDN. [ScrollViewer Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample, Grid with `LightBlue` color is the container control and have 2 child TextBoxes. You have limited the `Height` and `Width` of this grid which required a `ScrollBar` to see the child controls (Here it is textboxes). So you need to keep your `ScrollBar` inside the Parent `Grid` (LightBlue color grid).Please change your `XAML` like below to enable both horizontal and vertical `ScrollBars`

```
<Grid Width="387"
          Height="186"
          Background="LightBlue">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Height="110"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Margin="6,6,0,0"
                         Name="textBox1"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="375" />
                <TextBox Height="110"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Margin="6,122,0,0"
                         Name="textBox2"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="375"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: thanks vimal can you tell me what i did here?.and you send me any link or ref ...for best explanation of scroll viewer or all WPF